# Deploying Django on Shared Hosting (1and1) throws 500

Tags: python, django, .htaccess, shared-hosting

I have developed a project on Django that, locally, runs smoothly using the classic:

`python manage.py runserver`

Although the `python manage.py runfcgi` command throws me the html code of my website, I have experimented some problems when trying to access my website by means of the subdomain created.

Scenario: given a correctly installed version of django and flup (`python -c "import django"`), I have the following structure in the home folder of my 1and1 server:

```
/bla/bla/bla/test_django
    |-> manage.py
    |-> test_django
    |   |-> __init__.py
    |   |-> settings.py
    |   |-> urls.py
    |   |-> wsgi.py
    |-> dispatch.fcgi
    |-> .htaccess
```

Though I used to think that `.htaccess` should go in my "root" folder, I have copied it inside the `test_django` folder too. The contents are as follows:

`AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]`

The contents of my `dispatch.fcgi` (already chmoded to 755) are the following:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, '~/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'test_django.settings'

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

Where the `sys.path.insert` line is a local version of python installed (not sure about if correctly linked. However, I am not sure about what is this used for. Anyway, as said before, either with `python manage.py runfcgi` or with `./dispatch.fcgi`, the output displayed is the HTML of the website.

My question now is: is it necessary to do something else apart from pointing my subdomain test.whateverdomain.com to my `/bla/bla/bla/test_django` folder? This throws me a 500 error. I am afraid of missing the biggest point for me which would be the fact of redirecting the users to the executable file that will load the contents.

Comment: You really should look into deploying with WSGI and Gunicorn instead of fast cgi

Comment: Check your hosting's tutorial on how to deploy django application.

Comment: Unfortunately, 1and1 lacks from such a documentation. I will try to find new tutorials on WSGI. Will I have to point my domain to the wsgi.py file in the /bla/bla/bla/test_django/test_django folder?

Answer (score 0):

You should put your .fcgi file in a folder named `cgi-bin`. See [Installing a Django app on 1and1 Linux shared hosting](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20160406122629/http://robhogg.me.uk/post/2) for more instructions.

Comment: @makerGeek Used an Internet Archive cache. Perhaps the original site will be up again later, but this will work.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely critical that your calls to modify the system path are correct so that necessary python packages are accessible.

Those lines in your FCGI file should look something like:

```
sys.path.insert(0, "/home#/username/local_usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
sys.path.append("/home#/username/django_projects/mynewsite")
```

The first line is your python environment, the second is your Django project. I'd recommend using virtualenv, so, with that (changing the location of your python environment to be contained in dir '.env' with virtualenv named 'env') your entire FCGI file should look like:

```
#!/home#/username/.env/env/bin/python
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, "/home#/username/.env/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
sys.path.append("/home#/username/django_projects/test_django")
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'test_django.settings'

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

NOTE: The first line is **not** a comment.

Credit

http://www.binaryadventure.com/2013/10/23/django-on-bluehost-in-five-minutes/
https://help.asmallorange.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/305/0/installing-django-using-virtualenv